# Why is my js+css not compressed in production on Rails + Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gzip

I am running my producction environment with following settings, and it appears that it is minifying but is not gzipping/compressing the response.

```
  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true
```

Here is my js file, and the headers dont contain gzip or deflate???

```
$ curl -I http://sctest-perf.herokuapp.com/assets/application-1d21d488644b11e5610fa26bacdbc868.js
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Age: 0
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Content-length: 213394
Content-Type: application/javascript
Date: Fri, 08 Jun 2012 20:34:58 GMT
Etag: "1d21d488644b11e5610fa26bacdbc868"
Last-Modified: Wed, 30 May 2012 16:38:32 GMT
Status: 200 OK
X-Content-Digest: 914bc6f80b0619be63c1302821ccc24a082ace53
X-Rack-Cache: miss, store
X-Request-Id: 76cb22ef23b73c440878569eec42ed4d
X-Runtime: 0.001314
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to edit the `config.ru` file, located in your project root:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)

# Add beautifully gzipped responses
use Rack::Deflater

run YourApp::Application
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also try using one of these gems which are supposed to help optimize the serving of assets process further.

https://github.com/romanbsd/heroku-deflater

https://github.com/mattolson/heroku_rails_deflate

If I'm not mistaken using `use Rack::Deflater` also compresses images which wastes resources and isn't useful.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about this. Those are Heroku specific solutions though. But perhaps it's best to take a look at their source code and copy that than it is to just blindly add that line I provided. Thanks, I think I'm going to start using `heroku-deflater` from now on.